# binding buffers multiple times in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

[While learning opengl](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures), one bit of confusion is whether it is necessary to bind buffers like VAO
 or texture IDs multiple times without unbinding them?

With reference to the above link and the [full source code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.2.textures_combined/textures_combined.cpp) , I have come across 2 scenerios a bit distinct from each other.

**First**, the author creates a VAO(outside the maindraw loop) and binds the VAO using the  `glBindVertexArray(VAO)` then he **doesn't** unbind it using `glBindVertexArray(0);` , but he binds it again in the maindraw loop. My confusion, **Is this really necessary? Isn't the currently bound VAO already ... bound? Why bind it when it is already the active VAO?**

And,

**Second**, the author creates texture ID using:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);  
//some more code
glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
```

*outside the main draw loop* , but does this again *inside the main draw loop:  *

```
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
```

Two things that I don't understand in what he does is:

1. Why does he bind the texture ID again in the mainloop when he has
   done it outside of the mainloop?(This one is similar to VAO but I
   don't know yet if unbinding is possible in here)
2. Why does he select the active texture unit (using `glActiveTexture`)
   inside the loop? Couldn't it be done outside the main draw loop?

Comment: *"but he binds it again in the maindraw loop. My confusion, Is this really necessary?"* Not it is not. But if the author would extend the code and use more than 1 VAO, then it would be necessary.

Comment: `texture2` is not bound to texture unit 1 when it is creates (bound the 1st time). This is done later. Of course it would also be possible to do that before. Again, if the author would extend his program and want to draw different objects different textures, then it would be necessary to bind them before the drawing the object.

Comment: @Rabbid76 , which mean at this point the code is redundant and that `glActiveTexture` could also be done outside the loop? And what do you mean by: `texture2 is not bound to texture unit 1 when it is creates (bound the 1st time). This is done later.`?

Comment: At `glGenTextures(1, &texture2);` `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);` the current texture unit is 0, so `texture2`  is bound to texture unit 0.

Comment: The code in this tutorials has to be understood as template for novice, so it has to be extendable. Furthermore, the first goal of a tutorial is to explain relationships and not to write the highest optimized code.

Comment: "`At glGenTextures(1, &texture2); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2); the current texture unit is 0, so texture2 is bound to texture unit 0` " what is the effect? Is the first texture not drawn due to this? (I'm asking because only the second texture is being rendered) i.e. if I don't do the `Bind` and `Activate` as in the order he has specified

Comment: @Rabbid76 , if I `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);` then only the `texture1` is rendered, why do you think this happens?

Comment: [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml) binds a texture to specified target and in the current texture unit. If you bind 2 textures behind each other (2 calls to `glBindTexture`), without switching the texture unit in between (`glActiveTexture`), then just the 2nd texture is bound

Comment: @Rabbid76, yes that finally makes sense, wish this was in the answer section though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml) binds a texture to specified target and the current texture unit. The current texture unit is set by [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml). The current texture unit is a global state, and `glBindTexture` considers that state.

That meas when you do

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
```

after that `texture2` is bound to the current texture unit (`GL_TEXTURE0` by default) and the current texture unit is `GL_TEXTURE1`. Note `texture1`
is just bound for a short moment, but the binding is lost, when `texture2` is bound.

In compare, when you do

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
```

The current texture unit is explicitly set to `GL_TEXTURE0` and `texture1` is bound to texture texture unit 0. After that the current texture unit is switched to `GL_TEXTURE1` and  `texture2` is bound to texture unit 1 (because it is current at this moment).

---

Note, with the use of [Direct State Access](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) and [`glBindTextureUnit`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTextureUnit.xhtml) (since OpenGL 4.5) a texture can be bound to a texture unit directly. e.g.:

```cpp
glBindTextureUnit(GL_TEXTURE0, texture1);
glBindTextureUnit(GL_TEXTURE1, texture2);
```

Comment: For completeness, OpenGL4.5 (and extensions before that) allow you to bind textures to texture units directly with `glBindTextureUnit(GL_TEXTURE0, texture1)`. See [this answer on CG.se](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/how-to-do-texturing-with-opengl-direct-state-access) for more information.

Comment: Also, you can use `glBindTextures` before ARB_DSA if you want to bind textures to individual texture units.

Comment: @juztcode The value of `GL_TEXTURE0` is `0x0x84C0` (33985). The argument to [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml) has to be the enumerator constant, in compare to [`glBindTextureUnit`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTextureUnit.xhtml) where it has to be the index.

Comment: You mean when openGL started there were no shaders and were only textures? And by "GL_TEXTURE0 refers no where it names texture unit 0." you mean GL_TEXTURE0 refers to the address of texture unit 0?